# D3: data, enter, append pattern adds data to outer block

Tags: javascript, d3.js, append, enter

I'm using the D3 javascript library to render some basic web charts.  I want to add three `<path>` elements to an `<svg>` block, but D3 is adding the elements to the end of the `<html>` block instead.  Here's the complete html source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="d3.v2.js"></script>
<script>
var chartData = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
d3.select("html").select("body").append("svg")
  .data(chartData, function(d) { console.log("data d:", d); return d; })
  .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return d; });
</script>
</body>
```

Chrome's developer console shows the resulting html to be:

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css"></style></head><body>
<script src="d3.v2.js"></script>
<script>
var chartData = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
d3.select("html").select("body").append("svg")
  .data(chartData, function(d) { console.log("data d:", d); return d; })
  .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return d; });
</script><svg></svg>
</body><path d="1"></path><path d="2"></path><path d="3"></path></html>
```

The `<svg>` block was created, but for some reason, the `<path>` blocks are outside of it.  How can I correct this error, and put them inside the `<svg>` where they belong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you should have a high-level variable that only refers to the svg. Secondly, you should specify the height and width of the SVG when creating it. You don't need to specify a select of `html`, so:

```
var width = 400,
    height = 300;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

Now you can use the `svg` variable to append paths. It is recommended that you group the paths together (hence the `"g"` appended first). And you should also do a `selectAll` for paths, because you want to bind the data you are adding to the path elements. So:

```
svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(chartData)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return d; });
```

I recommend the D3 tutorials here: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/

Comment: Thank you!  It turns out that `.selectAll("path")` is the key part that was missing.

Answer (score 4):

For future visitors having a similar issue:

It appears the difference of behavior in this case (and similar others) between `select` and `selectAll` hinges on the fact that `selectAll` creates a *new group*.

D3's selection object is an array of arrays with some additional special properties. Each array corresponds to a group of objects. One property of the group is the `parentNode`, which is the node from which the initial `selectAll` was executed.

When the outermost selection is a `select`, the root is implicitly the document's root node--in this case, `html`.

Since `selectAll` creates a new group within the selection for each match (or entry), each group is assigned as its parent the node from which it derives. With `select`, since no new group is created, the original `parentNode` for each group is preserved, *even if it no longer accurately represents the parent of the nodes within the group*.

The `parentNode` also appears (empirically) to be the node to which `enter` selections' `append`ed nodes are attached.

This is why `select` produced the observed behavior, and `selectAll` remedied the problem.